# How to disable git source control on visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The "Git for Windows (32 bit)" process makes Visual Studio 2019's CPU usage high which bugs me because I have multiple programs open at a time, so my PC lags. I've looked up on how to disable git on Visual Studio 2019, [Tried the solutions on this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/586075/visual-studio-2019-its-impossible-to-turn-off-the.html), but they didn't seem to work. My Visual Studio 2019 version is 16.6.0.

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, is git turned off in Tools / Options / Source Control / Plug-in Selection? Does the git process start running for all projects, or only those with an existing git repo (.git subdirectory)?

Comment: Git does start running for all projects, and I didn't actually think of turning git off from settings - seems like I was looking at all websites. thank you, @dxiv

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Disabling git via going to Tools / Options / Source Control / Plug-in worked thanks to @dxiv's comment, I didn't know because I was looking at old answers.

Comment: No longer works. VS will simply bark at you that the current solution will be closed and refuse to disable git integration.

Comment: @T.S: It actually disables it for me. It just re-enables it every time I open a solution inside a git clone.

Comment: It's not working and should not be marked as the answer: after every restart of vs, it is re-enabled. It is really a pain and there seems to be no solution yet.

Comment: This did work for me. I got the warning saying my current solution will be closed, but after reopening it (after restarting VS) it seems to no longer track git changes

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022, it worked for me. It warned that it would need to close the solution. After having done this, I could reopen the solution, and it didn't track git info any more.

Answer (score 3):

I found that I was able to solve this issue by removing the .git folder that was in my user root directory.  It was C:\Users\MyUserName\.git I don't know where it came from.  It did not correspond to any of my legitimate GitHub repositories. It was large and seemed like it was constantly trying to index and prepare my entire user directory to push to a remote repository that did not exist.

This also resolved other ways the seemingly same issue presented itself in both VS2019 and VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the c:\users\yourusername.git folder and VS will stop showing GIT in Team Explorer.