# How to disable Git source control in Visual Studio 2019 v.16.8.xxx?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I am familiar with the post:
[How to disable git source control on visual studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966496/how-to-disable-git-source-control-on-visual-studio-2019)

But the accepted answer does not work anymore (v.16.8.6). When I disable Git feature in "Tools / Options / Source Control / Plug-in selection" globally for IDE, it is re-enabled again after I close/open my project.